# Using an array in where clause with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to do a query that would look like this :

```
"Select * FROM ... WHERE name in ($array)" which would be equal to 
"Select * FROM ... WHERE name in 'joe','william', ..."
```

How can I achieve that? I tried the following :

```
array = array.join("','")
```

But then here is the result I have (the backslashes appear due to the single quotes):

```
Select * FROM ... WHERE name in \'joe\',\'william\',..."
```

Comment: Javascript? This question has been asked and answered several times (tagged PHP).

Comment: What database API are you using?

Comment: I am using waterline, but I still do a full SQL query. I followed what was said on the other stack overflow threads, still there is the problem of the backslashes

Comment: your last snippet looks almost correct. just add paranthesis and remove the slashes (encoding) `IN ('joe', 'william')`